# How to plot expenses by month graph from rows data in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel table where each row describes an expense with its full date and the ammount of money as two seperate columns. I want to plot a bar graph where each bar describes the ammount of money I spent in specific month.

What is the simplest way to do it, with minimum adding of new columns to my table?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Insert>Chart>PivotChart

[image]

Put the Date field into the Axis (Categories) area in the PivotChart Fields dialog, then put the Amount into the Values area.

Normally this will automatically group the date as a month, like this:

[image]

If after adding the Date field to the Axis (Categories) area, you actually see something like this:

[image]

Then right-click any of the dates in the PivotTable and choose "Group" from the context menu:

[image]

In the Grouping dialog, select Months and click OK:

[image]

If the Group option is not available in the context menu from the PivotTable, make sure that the column holding the date in your data source is formatted as a date, then refresh the PivotTable and try again.

Comment: thanks! I have a continue question - what can I do if I have a column represents the amount of money and another column indicates whether it is an income or expense? I want to show different bars for incomes and expenses.

Comment: Drag that column into the Legend (Series) area of the PivotChart Fields dialog. That will make one set of bars for each value in that column, with each set having a different color.

Comment: It didn't work for me exactly that way but I got something similar. I will start to use pivot tables, it is great!